# SAS macro variable will not resolve

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Try again. This code will not work. It is a stupid code but still do not work.

```
data work.colnames;
      input cols $;
      cards;
      U1
      B1
      ;
run;


data work.test;
      input rp_U1 $ rp_B1 $;
      cards;
      col1 col2
      ;
run;

%macro maketest;
      proc sql;
           select cols
                  into :col separated by " "
            from colnames;         
      quit;
      %do i=1 %to 2;                          
            %let c = %qscan(&col,&i);                           
            %put rp_&c;
            proc sql;
                  create table test&i  as
                  select                 
                  rp_&c                  
                from work.test;             
            quit;    
    %end;
%mend;
%maketest;
```

I do get this error:

```
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *,   **, +, ',', -, '.', /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, AS, 
           CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE,   NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.
```

Which I find strange is if I try to get the columns without the rp_ this code works find. Also change

```
select                 
rp_&c
```

to

```
select                 
&c
```

Comment: turn on mprint (`options mprint;`) and attach the log to the question.  It will be much easier for us to help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro quoting you introduced by using `%QSCAN()` function instead of the `%SCAN()` function is probably causing trouble for the SAS parser.

In your code the macro variable C gets assigned the values of `U1` and `B1`, respectively.  But the values are macro quoted.  So when the parser sees `rp_&c` it thinks that those are two separate tokens so it treats it like token `rp_` followed by the token `U1` instead of a single token of `rp_U1`.

You should not need to quote a string that will be part of a variable name, so you should change

```
%let c = %qscan(&col,&i);
```

to

```
%let c = %scan(&col,&i);
```

But if you do need to have the macro quoting then you can use the `%unquote()` function to remove it. So change

```
select rp_&c
```

to

```
select %unquote(rp_&c)
```

Comment: In your code the macro variable C gets assigned the values `U1` and `B1`.

Comment: Okay. I need to read more about macro quoting. I see that I do not understand